# Как правильно организовать комментарии к сообщениям?

Tags: php

Как реализовать комментарии под сообщениями ?
Есть стена с списком сообщений и под каждым и них можно оставить Коментарии и под комментарием комментарий. Это нужно получается деревом выводить. По типу как рекурсия в категориях товаров ? или не так ? я просто с этим не сталкивался. Подскажите.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое понятие как Nested Sets.  Т.е. уже продуманная структура для хранения дерева в базе. Общая суть в записи хранится левый и правый отступы. Для дочерних элементов эти значения находятся в диапазоне между значениями родителя. Т.е. эти индексы идут через все записи без разрывов.

Описывать подробно -тут надо приводить большой текст с листингами и картинками для наглядности. Потому даю ссылку на хорошую [статью про netsedsets](http://www.getinfo.ru/article610.html)

А выводить да, можно с использованием рекурсии. А можно анализировать те самые отступы из базы.